# A sufficient condition to obtain a function with zero average

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N\geq 2$. Let $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ which is the class of all measurable functions $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}:=\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}<\infty.
$$
Let $1<q<p^*=\frac{N-p}{N-p}$ if $1<p<N$ and $1<q<\infty$ if $p\geq N$. Assume that
$$
\int_{\Omega}|u|^{q-2}u\,dx=0.
$$
Then can we obtain $\int_{\Omega}u\,dx=0$? If so, can someone please help me with this?

If we assume
$$
\int_{\Omega}|u|^{q-2}u\,dx=0,
$$
then I can get $\int_{\Omega}(u_+^{q-1}-u_-^{q-1})\,dx=0$, where $u_{+}=\max\{u,0\}$ and $u_-=\max\{-u,0\}$. After this I get no clue. Kinldy help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think this is true? imho it should be easy to find counterexamples for $N=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an explicit counterexample, but a way to construct one.

Consider
$$
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } & 0\leq x<1,\\
-2^{-1/q} & \text{ if } & 1\leq x\leq 3.
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that $\int_0^3 |u|^{q-1}u\, dx =0$, but $u$ doesn't have zero average. To build a function in $W^{1,p}$ you can linearly interpolate between the two values as
$$
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } & 0\leq x<a,\\
\ell(x) & \text{ if } & a<x<b,\\
-2^{-1/q} & \text{ if } & b\leq x\leq 3,
\end{cases}
$$
for some $0<a<1<b<3$ and $\ell$ is the linear function with value $1$ at $x=a$ and $-2^{-1/q}$ at $x=b$. This function is always in $W^{1,\infty}$, and by choosing $a,b$ appropriately you can check that $\int_0^3|u|^{q-1} u\, dx =0$, but $u$ doesn't have zero average.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about the converse? If $\int_{\Omega}u\,dx=0$, then is the integral $\int_{\Omega}|u|^{q-2}u\,dx=0$?

Comment: @Mathguide: You can use the example above to show that this doesn't hold either (set $v=|u|^{q-1}u$, then $v$ has zero average, but the other integral won't vanish).